Are probabilities correct in elements of toss in binomial distribution in numpy python?
I saw in many tutorials below code in numpy for Binomial Distribution:
x = random.binomial(n=10, p=0.5, size=10)

n - number of trials.
p - probability of occurrence of each trial (e.g. for toss of a coin 0.5 each).
size - The shape of the returned array.
in above example number of trial is 11(10+1(zero)). in this sample p=0.5  .
When the number of states is 10, if we want to consider the probability of each of them as equal, it will be equal to 0.1. But in this example, the probability is 0.5. I think 0.5 is suitable for a coin that has two modes. Can someone clear this up for me?

I don't understand your question. A binomial experiment only has two states by definition. n and p are the two parameters that determine how your binomial dsitribution will look like.

@Frede https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_random_binomial.asp

what is this link supposed to tell me?
What do you mean when you say "states is 10"? The number of different outcomes in a random experiment? Or the number of repeats of a random experiment?

n is the number of TRIALS (repeats of the experiment). Each trial can go one of TWO ways. (That’s why it’s called BInomial). For a fair coin, each of those two ways has equal probability of 1/2 or 0.5. So, p=0.5.

Darwin, if there are more than two possible outcomes, then that's called a multinomial distribution. A web search will find some resources about that. By the way, this question is off topic for SO; for related questions try [stats.SE] instead.
